# Set the header in urllib.request python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

What is the meaning of **body** (refers to?) in the code below?

```
headers = ['Content-length']=str(len(bytes(body, 'utf-8')))

return urllib.request.Request(theurl, bytes(body, 'utf-8'), headers)
```

Sourse : [BadStatusLine exception raised when returning reply from server in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297408/badstatusline-exception-raised-when-returning-reply-from-server-in-python-3)

Comment: Presumably it's the body you're going to send with the HTTP request.

Comment: @smarx I am utterly unable to understand. body to HTTP? Kindly elaborate. I am a newbie.

Comment: @smarx In this line we are not sending any body to HTTP . req = urllib.request.Request(Link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'})

Comment: If you're not sending any body, then you don't need a `Content-Length` header. Maybe you can ask a different question that relates to what you're actually trying to do.